# WCF method that takes an object as parameter that can also accept deserialized xml of that object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a method in my wcf service that takes an object as a parameter.  A mainframer needs to call this method now so i would like the service to be able to handle him passing me the deserialized xml for the object. Is this possible to do without me creating another method that accepts a string?

Answer (score 0):

Since most WCF web services communicate via SOAP, any client that can send a valid SOAP message with the proper data contract reflected in the body, should be interoperable.

You could use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to conduct a simple/straightforward test.